# How to visually customize SonarQube?

Tags: css, sonarqube

I am looking at customizing a SonarQube installation for our organization. I know the dashboards are highly configurable, i.e. http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Customizing+Dashboards but what I would like to do is be able to easily change the CSS for the site - for instance, including a company logo at the top, and being able to easily re-apply these changes as we upgrade Sonar.

So I guess there are two parts to this:
-Is there a way, within the Sonar framework, to make visual customizations?
-If there isn't, what is the best way to make these changes in a repeatable way so that we can deal with Sonar upgrades gracefully?

Googling for things like "sonar css" gets me results about using Sonar to check the quality of CSS files.

I know I can just edit the sonar.css files directly and have the changes kick in, but I'm trying to figure out the best path that will allow future upgrades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're primarily looking to add your company logo, take a look at the [Branding Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Branding+Plugin).  Otherwise, writing your own plugin may be the "best" route to apply over time/upgrades, but the web UI is currently getting a lot of changes so compatibility across upgrades may be sketchy.

Answer (score 2):

The latest installation has an option to change company logo.

Go to Administration->General Settings (default page)->Look & Feel and can provide the URL of the logo.

Answer (score 0):

Manually hacking into the SonarQube CSS and template files is not a viable solution, especially given the current development axis in the 4.x branch.

If you need branding, you can use the "Project Logo" and "Project Comment" widgets.

Comment: Where do you configure the "Project Logo"?

Comment: Administration->General Settings (default page)->Look & Feel and can provide the URL of the logo